# Javascript loop dropdownlist options

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I play an online game and love to play it but when I try to find a good server to play on it takes like 10 mins plus find a good server with players on it.

But then I worked out if I paste `Game.currentGame.ui.options.servers.<SERVER VALUE HERE>.population` in the google chrome console it would show me how many players are in that server but that still takes a lot of time to do so I was wondering would there be a way to display the population value of each server in the `<select>` next to the server's name using javascript or something else?

I hope someone could point me in the right direction on how I could do this or if this can even be done maybe with javascript?

```
<select class="hud-intro-server">
<optgroup label="asia servers">
<option value="v8617903">asia #1 </option>
<option value="v8617895">asia #2 </option>
<option value="v8617899">asia #3 </option>
<option value="v8617900">asia #4 </option>
<option value="v8617898">asia #5 </option>
<option value="v8617894">asia #6 </option>
<option value="v8617901">asia #7 </option>
<option value="v8617902">asia #8 </option>
<option value="v8617897">asia #9 </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

.

```
Game.currentGame.ui.options.servers.<SERVER VALUE HERE>.population
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+loop+dropdownlist+options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code in console, the select options will now show player count before text

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-intro-server")[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x.options[i].text = Game.currentGame.ui.options.servers[x.options[i].value].population + " " + x.options[i].text;
    }
```